# AMD 6700 video card powers monitor through DP to HDMI adapter but not 3 simultaneous monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

AMD 6700 video card powers monitor through DP to HDMI adapter but not 3 simultaneous monitors. Is this because of my DisplayPort adapter? Specs on the DP to HDMI converter box,

DisplayPort to HDMI Converter with Audio

Introduction
This is a DisplayPort to HDMI signal format converter for interfacing next generation DisplayPort PC and notebook computers with high definition displays. DisplayPort offers a unified, scalable, and cost effective interface for embedded and external display applications. As desktop and notebook PCs are increasingly transitioning from conventional analog type interaces to DisplayPort, the converter facilitates the transition by offering seamless connectivity between new DisplayPort PC and the installed base HDMI mointors and projectors. 
If offers solutions for digital entertainment center, HDTC  retails and show site, HDTV, STB, DVE AND Projector factory, noise space and security concerns, data center control, information distribution, conference room presentation, shool and conrporate training environments.
**Features**

-Support DisplayPort 1.1a input and HDMI OUTPUT. 
-sUPPORT hdmi HIGHEST VIDEO RESOLUTION 1080P. sUPPORT hdmi    225mHZ/2.25gBPS PER CHANNEL      (6.75Gbps all channel) bandwidth. 
-Support    HDMI 12bit per channel      (36bit all channel) deep color 
-Supports    uncompressed audio such as    LPCM.
-Powered from DisplayPort source

Comment: Are you sure that 6700 can actually drive 3 monitors? Most "consumer" cards I've seen in the last few years can only provide output for 2 monitors at the same time.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, yes they can. All AMD Radeon HD cards in the 6000 series should be able to drive at least 3 monitors.

Comment: Many of the 5000 can also.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that your adapter is a **passive** DisplayPort adapter. You need an **active** adapter to be able to run more than two displays off of one card.